# How can I search for a question that I commented on?

Tags: support, questions, comments, search

If I deleted my browser's history, is there any way to find a question that I commented on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see every comment you've ever left (except deleted ones) on your profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427849/zey?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: But this is not exactly searchable in the sense we usually mean when speaking about using a web browser.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's true. Not to be overly pedantic about it, though, but including comments in site search results is a feature request, not a support question. :)

Comment: Well, that's true enough, @Anna.